# Use Lambda function to read a certain Cloudwatch alarm status and its metrics with Python

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3, amazon-cloudwatch, cloudwatch-alarms

I'm completely new with boto.
I created a Cloudwatch alarm for a certain Kinesis metrics. Now I want to write a Lambda function which can read the alarm status and the corresponding metrics value in every 5 minutes.

Does anyone have experiences with this task and can help me?

following is what I'm currently having in my code:

```
import json
import boto3

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    cloudwatch = boto3.resource('cloudwatch')
    alarm = cloudwatch.Alarm('Test') 
    response = alarm.describe_alarms()
    return{reponse}
```

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways of doing this. One would be:

1. Add/modify [execution role](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-intro-execution-role.html) of your function with permissions to read CloudWatch metrics.
2. Use boto3's [cloudwatch](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/cloudwatch.html) to read the metrics you require. You already started doing this.
3. Setup a [CloudWatch Event scheduled rule](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/ScheduledEvents.html) to trigger your lambda function every 5 minutes.